# Should we group technical terms (like 1080p) into more generic tags (like HDVideo)?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [1080p](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1080p) tag currently, which means that in theory we probably need [480i](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/480i), [480p](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/480p), [720i](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/720i), [720p](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/720p), [1080i](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1080i), [4k](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4k) etc.

That seems a little too specific to me for this type of site, and the list will only get longer.  What if instead we use catch-all tags like [hdvideo](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdvideo) and [ultrahdvideo](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultrahdvideo) instead and use synonym tags to point [1080p](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1080p) and its brethren at the former and 4k and its variants at the latter?

Similarly, a [dvi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi) tag could be used to point synonyms [dvi-i](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi-i), [dvi-d](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi-d), [dvi-a](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi-a) at; we could handle versioned [hdmi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdmi) tags ([hdmi1.0](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdmi1.0), [hdmi1.1](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdmi1.1) etc.) as synonyms too.

Do people think this would prove too blunt a tool when it comes to searching for tags, should we allow proliferation of the specific tags instead?

Comment: Interesting post on [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/977654/what-is-the-difference-between-4k-uhd-and-qhd-do-we-agree-on-one-official-reso) about resolutions.

Answer (score 4):

I am for the idea of having [1080p](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1080p), [720p](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/720p), etc. be merged into [high-definition](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-definition) and having [4k](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4k) (and anything higher resolution) be merged into [ultra-high-definition](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultra-high-definition). The only thing I do not know what to do with is [quad-hd](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quad-hd). I'm thinking it should be it's own tag as it fits in the middle of HD and UHD.

I also like having all the DVIs merged into [dvi](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dvi) if needed. I don't think this will much of an issue right away, but might be later. HDMI1.0 and others will be even less of an issue.

Comment: Quad-HD should definitely be its own tag because it's a very specific type of resolution (more so than any other one) when it comes to computers (usually laptops).

Comment: I agree. QHD can be also associated with mobile phones (LG G3 as example).

Comment: There will likely be a plethora of terms in the mobile space going forward for various resolutions and tech, so this seems like a decent distinction to make.  I can see an argument being made to separate brand specific terms like retina too

Comment: I considered high-definition as a tag too, but it can apply to audio too, and then the synonyms of 1080p would not be appropriate, hence I thought HD-Video would be a decent compromise

Comment: @AdamComerford If I am not mistaken, retina refers to the pixel density, not the resolution of the device. Also, we could use the tag [hd-audio] if we need it. Whenever I hear "HD", i think of displays.

Comment: that makes sense - we can also have the tag description make it clear that the generic terms is for video, even refer to hd-audio - I can live with that

Comment: @Cfinley To be exact, Retina refers to a pixel density *and expected distance* - something that would be considered Retina on a desktop computer might not be on a phone. I'm in favor of merging DVI versions into one tag, but I'm not sure yet on the HD things.

Comment: Keep in mind in not so many years "ultra high definition" will change..

Comment: @enderland Then we can either rename the tag or merge it with the new buzzword that replaces it.

Answer (score 1):

We shouldn't be [creating tags just to make synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146140/186281) of them. Discussing merges/synonyms of *existing* tags makes sense, but if we don't have certain (hypothetical) tags yet, they shouldn't fall into our discussions.

Tags can be reorganized in the future. If you think we need one of those possible synonyms now, add it to a question and lets see if it sticks. It's entirely possible we won't need at the `dvi-*` tags. But, if those tags won't stick, there is no sense in creating them just to create a synonym.

Comment: the examples I chose are illustrative rather than prescriptive - I was using them to make a point rather than definitively saying they should be created - I would be surprised if DVI and Displayport don't make an appearance as we grow the number of questions, but I suppose it is possible.  Point taken though - if no one ever thinks to tag something DVI-I or DVI-D, then no point in creating a synonym for no reason.  I think the 1080p and other resolutions should still be aggregated though

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem we don't have right now though. Or, worse, creating a problem. I can easily see a requirement being 1080p support and no lower. Tagging it high-definition would be misleading as someone could assume that the user would also accept 720p. This isn't to say the idea is without merit, but I think we need more questions with these types of tags before we can determine how to handle groups of them.

Comment: I don't see how asking a question for discussion, when a site is in private beta is creating a problem.  I thought it was the point in fact, but I appreciate the opinion from the requirements perspective.  As some feedback, if you left the first two sentences off your comment, it would be a far more constructive response

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I'll try to be more clear in my responses. The problem I was referring to was with the combined tags for high-definition but possible resolution requirements that contridict that tag (1080 vs 720). There is not a problem with this discussion at all. Sorry I came off that way.

Answer (score 0):

[uhdtv](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uhdtv)/[uhd](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uhd) (Ultra HD television) can replace 4K UHD (2160p) and 8K UHD (4320p).

[hdtv](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hdtv)/[hd](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hd) can replace 1080p/1080i & 720p. They are standard HDTV resolutions.

Below HD there are a few others but it would be easier to choose [sd](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sd) as Adam says.

According to DVI, there is no point in making so many tags. One is sufficient. People mostly associate the interface with a digital signal.

The same thing with HDMI.

Comment: Anything below HD is considered SD.

Comment: Not entirely. LD is below the SD. I'll edit my answer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-definition_television

Comment: I don't foresee there being too many people that make the distinction between the DVI versions, just that we should have them for completeness (and pedants of course).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any point in creating extremely specific tags when we can create broad tags that encompass anything they might cover via synonymous tags and/or tag excerpts.

"High-definition" shouldn't be written out in tags, only in excerpts. This will keep them short and simple but still searchable. For HD audio, the regular HD tag excerpt can suggest the use of [hd-audio](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hd-audio).

And tags for individual resolutions should be synonymous to their respective HD types if they ever pop up. Basically, any little bits of information such as version numbers and exact resolutions should be kept to the excerpts.

As Andy stated, discussing nonexistent tags is pointless, but since [1080p](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1080p) has been created, I feel this is a valid subject to worry about.